# Using Texo in Play 2

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, playframework-2.0, eclipselink

I am using the eclipse Texo project for my domain classes, which I have moved across to Play 2.3.8.

I configured according to this https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.8/JavaJPA adding the

```
        <non-jta-data-source>pssh2</non-jta-data-source>
```

to my existing persistance.xml

I added a GlobalSettings subclass to initialize the DaoRegistry like so:

```
public void beforeStart(Application app) {
    Logger.info("Application has started");
    Properties prop = getProperties();      
    ParcelSystemSimulationModelPackage.initialize();
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(prop.getProperty("persistname"));
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    EntityManagerProvider.getInstance().setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    EntityManagerProvider.getInstance().setCurrentEntityManager(em);
    EntityManagerProvider.getInstance().setUseCurrentEntityManagerPattern(true);
```

After moving the ecore file into a jar and putting it in the lib directory. It initializes the Texo generated ModelPackage. But it cannot find the datasource required in the createEntityManager line inthe source above. I get:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [pssh2].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: pssh2 not found
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:762) ~[eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204) ~[eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304) ~[eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336) ~[eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302) ~[eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b]
    at com.example.pss.Global.beforeStart(Global.java:44) ~[na:na]
```

I have setup the datasource in my application.conf file like so:

```
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:file://C:/Users/david.wynter/git/pss/db/pss_db; DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE"
db.default.user="sa"
db.default.password="*******"
#
# You can expose this datasource via JNDI if needed (Useful for JPA)
db.default.jndiName=pssh2
jpa.default=pssh2
```

Comment: I added a System.out.println at the onStart method in my GlobalSettings subclass, and it is clear it does not get called. So wondering what class gets called for application startup?

Comment: And added application.global=com.example.Global to application.conf. No change

Comment: OK, discovered beforeStart means beforeHandlingTheFirstHTTPRequest, rather than before starting the HTTP Server. It only gets triggered when I hit it with the first HTTP request, a JSON GET, which seems mad if you have a bunch of components to initialize that are time expensive.

Comment: I have updated the question above